Interpreting symmetrical geometric construction in Fortescue 1918
In his 1918 paper, "METHOD OF SYMMETRICAL CO-ORDINATES APPLIED TO THE SOLUTION OF POLYPHASE NETWORKS", Fortescue gives 2 graphical methods of finding his symmetrical components from a set of 3 phasors (vectors).
On pages 1035-1036 he shows his first graphical approach to finding the symmetrical components of a set of power system voltages $E_a$,$E_b$, and $E_c$.  It is straight forward and understandable.  Below are the equations for calculating these symmetrical components ($E_0, E_1, E_2$) from the 3 voltages and $\alpha=1@120°$ is the phase shift operator.
$$E_{012} = A^{-1}  E_{abc} = \begin{pmatrix}
E_0\\ E_1 \\ E_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$E_{012}=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
E_a + E_b + E_c\\
E_a + \alpha E_b + \alpha^2 E_c\\
E_a + \alpha^2 E_b + \alpha E_c\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, my question is related to the first page of his Appendix II on page 1114 of his paper:

I don't understand how to find the 2 equilateral triangles he is describing in the text beneath Fig 18 (both triangles have BC as a base).  Any help will be appreciated, this is not HW as I'm way past that in my life.
thanks

In general, a question on this site should be self-contained and not require an external link. Hence I've added the image and the accompanying paragraph from the text. (I'm not sure this is sufficient context but it's a start.)

Thank you @Semiclassical

Suppose we are given points $A,B,C$. Draw two circles, one centered at $B$ passing through point $C$ and the other centered at $C$ through point $B$. These will intersect at two points $P,Q$. By construction, these two points are each equidistant from $B,C$. Hence $\triangle BCP$ and $\triangle BCQ$ both constitute equilateral triangles with $\overline{BC}$ as common edge. Now take the centers of these triangles to get the points $E,F$ and proceed from there.

I decided to give an algebraic explication of Fortescue's construction using complex numbers. Suppose we start with complex numbers $z_A,z_B,z_C$ corresponding to the three given points. For now I will  assume (WLOG?) that the centroid of these points is $0$: $$\overline{z}=\frac13(z_a+z_b+z_c)=0$$
Next, I will claim that constructing the points $P,Q$ amounts to the following:
$$
z_p=z_b+(z_c-z_b)e^{\pi i/3}, \quad z_q=z_b+(z_c-z_c)e^{-\pi i/3}
$$
The logic here is that, if we don't include the phase factor, then adding $z_c-z_b$ simply moves $B$ to $C$. Including the $\pi/3=60^\circ$ phase factors means that, instead, we arrive at points which are $\overline{BC}$ away from $B$ but with $\angle BCQ=-\angle BCQ=60^\circ$.
The points $E,F$ are now the centroids of the triangles $\triangle BCP$ and $\triangle BCQ$:
$$
z_e = \frac13(z_b+z_c+z_p),\quad
z_f = \frac13(z_b+z_c+z_q)
$$
The point $E_{a1}$ correspond to the reflections of $E,F$ with respect to the centroid of $\triangle ABC$.  Similarly, the points $E_{b1},E_{c1}$ correspond to rotating $E$ around this centroid by 60 degrees. But we already assumed the centroid was at the origin, so
$$z_{a1}=-z_e,\quad z_{b1}=z_e e^{i\pi/3},\quad z_{c1}=z_e e^{-i\pi/3}$$
The construction of $E_{a2},E_{b2},E_{c2}$ similarly yields
$$z_{a2}=-z_f,\quad z_{b2}=z_f e^{i\pi/3},\quad z_{c2}=z_f e^{-i\pi/3}$$
It remains to verify that these points satisfy Fortescue's algebraic construction. For instance, one can check (though it's beyond my patience) that points $E_{a1},E_{a2}$ can also be expressed as
\begin{split}
z_{a1}&=\frac13(z_a+e^{2\pi i/3}z_b+e^{4\pi i/3}z_c)\\
z_{a2}&=\frac13(z_a+e^{4\pi i/3}z_b+e^{2\pi i/3}z_c)
\end{split}
Multiplying these by $-e^{\pm \pi i/3}=e^{\mp 2\pi i/3}$ yields similar results for the remaining points.

Your assumption is that the zero-sequence component is zero (e.g. $E_0=0$).  What about the case when it is non-zero?
